# Does OpenLDAP support selective user password hashing 5 users with {CRYPT} rest with {SSHA}?

Tags: openldap

I want to hash user passwords in OpenLDAP 2.4.32 selectively Means some of the users are hashed using {SSHA} and some of the users are hashed using {CRYPT}.
Can that be done in OpenLDAP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the [OpenLDAP Guide #14.4. Password Storage](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Password%20Storage). Not only can you do that per user, you can do that per-password where users have multiple passwords.